# Laravel Eloquent Where Query with multiple words

Tags: laravel

I have the following query (cut for brevity):

```
    $employees = Employee::where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                 ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
```

Now this works when the user inputs a single name like 'John' or 'Smith', but when they input 'John Smith' it doesn't find anything. Am I missing an extra orWhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Employee::where(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",lastname)'), 'LIKE', "%' . $query . '%"))
```

Comment: Thank you! They all work but this one is the shortest!

Comment: Beware: The answer is wide open for sql injection. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add a 3rd `orWhere`. For our search function we use something like this:

```
Employee::whereraw("COALESCE(last_name, '') LIKE '%$query%'")
    ->Orwhereraw("COALESCE(first_name, '') LIKE '%$query%'")
    ->Orwhereraw("COALESCE(last_name + ', ' + first_name, '') LIKE '%$query%'")
```

Adding Coalesce seemed to help with some issues we had when we first implemented it, not sure if it is necessary in your case though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

$fullName = trim($query);

```
$employees  = Employee::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"), 'LIKE', "%".$fullName."%")->get();
```

You are concatenating the values in database for `first_name + ' ' + last_name` and then using like to find the matching records.

Comment: Beware: The answer is wide open for sql injection. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: @MuratTutumlu not really, the DB::raw is used in column concatenation where there is no used defined variable passed. and the query string is passed in the `where()` argument which is safe for injections.